# How do I open a selected folder in Google Docs in the Mac Finder?

Tags: google-drive, mac

Often when I'm browsing my Google Docs in Chrome, I find that I want to open the same folder in the Mac OS X Finder so that I can edit one of the native documents. Right now I'm forced to open my root Google Drive folder and then browse the same folder.

How can I do this more quickly, directly to the right folder?